# Sendkeys to Webelement causes new tabs \ window to open

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am automating 'facebook' using Selenium-webdriver (using Java) trying to send string to a text-field (as a comment to a post) will result in opening a few tabs in the browser (chrome) and also a new window of the browser.
Did anyone encounter this weird behavior ?

This is my code:

```
WebElement postBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@title,'Write a comment')])[1]"));
postBox.sendKeys("testing testing, 1.. 2.. 3..");
```

Comment: Please add your code so someone can help you.

Comment: @MattiasLindberg - Added my code.

Comment: it's probably just the facebook application.  you'll have to account for it.

Comment: @MattiasLindberg I actually encountered this problem in 2 other websites. This made me think that there is a deeper problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use cssSelector by the fact that xpath can fail depending on your browser.

CssSelector : `By.CSSselector(.innerwrap textarea)`

More info about CSSselector [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).